# EF Core 6 - One to Many Self Referencing Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a self navigation reference on a third party database for an ETL I am developing.

Using Entity Framework Core 6.0.9 (EF Core 6)

**Constraint:** The database schema cannot be changed, so need solution that doesn't involve creating columns or changing key definitions.

Database was scaffolded to generate the schema and models.

I am attempting to modify the models and OnConfiguring context in order to add navigations **without** changing the database schema.

I am running into difficulty with a self referencing group relationship and looking for some help!

Class models below show the relationships/navigation I'd like to achieve:

```
public class Widget
{
    public int    Id      { get; set; } // same Id value as WidgetDetail.Id
    public int    GroupId { get; set; } // same GroupId value as WidgetDetail.GroupId
    public string Name    { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties:
    public WidgetDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetDetail
{
    public int    Id          { get; set; }
    public int    GroupId     { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties:
    public Widget              Widget      { get; set; }
    public IList<WidgetDetail> WidgetGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Following was modified into the OnConfiguring for this entity:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WidgetDetail>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(wd => wd.Id);

    entity
        .HasOne<Widget>(wd => wd.Widget)
        .WithOne(w => w.Detail)
        .HasForeignKey<WidgetDetail>(wd => wd.Id);
}
```

I can query the data into the models and that relationship/navigation works as expected, all GOOD.

Now I want to enable the `WidgetGroup` list and I am not sure how to do that in Fluent API. I can find plenty of references using two tables but in my case it's one (I think). This is what I tried:

```
entity
    .HasMany<WidgetDetail>(wd => wd.WidgetGroup)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(wd => wd.GroupId);
```

- This associates data in `WidgetGroup` based on `Id` and not based on `GroupId`.
- Wrapping my head around `HasMany`, `HasOne`, with one, with many is probably tripping me up and I need some more caffeine ;).

  - I also don't know if I am defining keys correctly - maybe it should be a composite key? If I do that, how do I specify to use only half of the composite key?

Many questions and I'm new-ish to Entity Framework (let alone EFCore).

Database Table Schema details

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WidgetDetail](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Widget](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [GroupId] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Data may look like this:
Widget

| Id | GroupId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Blue Cat |
| 2 | 1 | Red Cat |
| 3 | 2 | Dog |

Widget Detail

| Id | GroupId | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Level 0 Cat - Easy to raise, newbies welcome! |
| 2 | 1 | Level 1 Cat - This cat is difficult - pros only |
| 3 | 2 | Level 0 Dog - Who doesn't love dogs? |

Anyone know what I am doing wrong or have any suggestions for me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: EF Core and ETL? Strange choice.

Comment: "The database schema cannot be changed" - but can you add `VIEW` objects?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the database schema you have like table and column definitions, as well as primary/foreign keys. Include sample data to show where you have one-to-many records in your database.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Please elaborate on why you believe EF Core and ETL are a strange choice?

Comment: @Dai I am not allowed to add VIEW objects at this time though that is a very good idea and I will try to enable that in future

Comment: @PhideasAmbrosianus EF is meant for OLTP, but ETL represents an OLAP workload. OLAP and OLTP are somewhat opposites to each other, in some ways. EF is kinda klunky for OLAP because Linq-to-Entities is still very limited in expressiveness compared to raw SQL.

Comment: @Progman Thanks for the question, I've updated post to include the details I have available. I don't see any primary/foreign keys defined in this table like I would normally - from what I can tell it's keyless data

Comment: EF Core has nothing compared to high-load ETL. If you just insert several records, it is ok. But if you manipulate/transform/streams a tons of records it is far away from ideal.

Comment: @PhideasAmbrosianus The sample data only show One-to-One relations. Please [edit] the sample data to show the One-to-Many relationship.

Comment: @Progman - the one to many relationship would be. Widget Detail with Id = 1 has two related records via the GroupId. That's the one to many relationship that I am seeing in this data that I need to associate.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications on the OLAP and ETL workloads - Lots to learn there on my part so I appreciate the insight. I did some reading, I think  HTAP (hybrid as some transactional automation will be services that spin out of this) is a better description of what we're doing here and definitely not managing a lot of data at this time.

Comment: Following-up on this, I am further along down the pipe and wanted to share positive experience with https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions , seems to be an excellent improvement and MIT license with a boatload of industry usage by the looks of things.